# Why is my SQL Server Integration with Salesforce returning a Invalid Session Error Code when our table schema is changed?

Tags: sql-server, salesforce, procedure, dbamp

In our SQL Server we refresh, every 30 minutes, the below tables using this procedure

```
`exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' ,'Case'                            ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'Account'                     ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'User'                        ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'RecordType'                  ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'End_Customer__c'             ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'Access__c'                   ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'Pricing_Entry__c'            ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'Assets__c'                   ,'Yes','no'
exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE' , 'Component__c'                ,'Yes','no'`
```

This works most of the time, however, when a new field is added to the table via Salesforce. The above stops working, I am then having to use a manual function as a work around to get the code running again.

Our SQL is currently slow and mismanged, is it possible this is part of a larger issue

This is the error that is recieved

```
` Using last run time of 2022-11-21 13:48:00 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  19:15:56: Identified 1123 updated/inserted rows. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  19:15:56: Error: Fixed_Asset_Tracking_URL__c exists in the delta table but does not exist in the local table or has a different definition. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  19:15:56: Table schema has changed. The table will be replicated instead. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  --- Starting SF_Replicate for Case V5.1.9 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0) `
```

The below is what I use to Replicate the table, then I switch back to the Refresh function and it will work again

`` `exec [SalesforceBackup].dbo.SF_Replicate'SALESFORCE' ,'Case','pkchunk,batchsize(7500)'` ``

I believe the Refresh function should be adding the column anyway, but is there a way to automatically solve the error by including teh new column with my manual intervention

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `SF_Refresh` only refreshes the table data, not the table schema.

You'll want to either use `SF_Mirror` or have a `TRY / CATCH` block on your TSQL code and use both `SF_Refresh` and `SF_Replicate`.

Check out the documentation for SF_Mirror [here](https://cdn.cdata.com/help/AFH/dbampd/SF_MirrorBasics.html)

As for the `TRY / CATCH` block as suggested above, this is how we do it at our org using a stored procedure to warehouse our Salesforce data

```
BEGIN TRY

EXEC SF_Refresh 'SALESFORCE', 'Case'

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

EXEC SF_Replicate 'SALESFORCE', 'Case'

END CATCH
```

EDIT: Just realized how old this question is so hopefully this helps out someone :)